# C# executing function in inheriting classes from main class array

Tags: c#, inheritance

Sorry in advance for my English.

I'm doing scripts in unity and what I want to achieve is:

I have a multiple classes (B1, B2, B3) and every one of them inherit from A class. In my code I have container for A objects, that mostly contain B classes. A class and B classes have function called MyFunction() and there is the problem: when I want to call this function on object of class i.e. B2, when its in vector for A class objects, when I call MyFunction(), there is executed version from A, not from B2. I tried to solve this problem in best way I could, but I ended with "if B1, then ... else if B2, then ..." type of solution which is not something I want.

As example of my ugly solution (used in ImmaDed() ), I link my scripts, without every line that is not needed in this example:

http://pastebin.com/4BY0RkBN

Thank you very much for any effort in advance.

Comment: Can you include in your question the relevant portions of class `A`, `B1` & `B2`? (*NB*: Not 100's of lines of code, just the class declarations and the delcaration for `MyFunction)`

Comment: Is `MyFunction` virtual?

Comment: Can U include bit of your code to understand

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: I included them in link, A class is named Ship and B classes are PlayerShip and EnemyShip, MyFunction class is called ImmaDed(), I though its better to make pastes and link them, then pasting everything in my message

Comment: Dude I have no idea what to do when I follow that link, I don't use that site. It's a barrier to having someone help you, please include some code directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) MSDN page, you will need to declare your `MyFunction` method as `virtual`:

> The **virtual** keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer,
>   or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
>   class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that
>   inherits it.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void MyFunction() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your sub classes do something like so:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override void MyFunction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for working solution, I have no idea if there is need to me to say that my question is answered and it can be closed now

Comment: @Hababa: Under the score of each question there should be a green mark. Clicking it will accept the respective solution, denoting that that particular solution answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new myfunction in class B it shadows on the same function on class A. in this state you have to define a variable of class be to call that function. but if you have a variable of class A that point to an object of Class B
(ex: a list of A and B objects) , you should define MyFunction an virtual in Class A :

```
public virtual void MyFunction(){}
```

then override it in class B :

```
public override void MyFunction(){}
```

and if you want the function in class B do the same as class A override myfunction in class B like this:

```
 public override void MyFunction()
{
//your code
base.myfunction();// execute myfunction in class A
//your code
}
```